# Get resource ID from URI or Bitmap

Tags: android, uri, android-resources, android-file, android-bitmap

Is there anyway I can find resource ID from Bitmap, URI, file path or file name of an image? These images are written by my app. So is there any chance I can find the resource ID?

Basically, I have GIF images stored in my SD Card (which are created by my app). I want to load those images to my viewer. For that, I am using [GIF Movie View library](https://github.com/sbakhtiarov/gif-movie-view/blob/master/src/com/basv/gifmoviewview/widget/GifMovieView.java). In that file, `setMovieResource()` expecting an int (resource ID). But I have all other info like bitmap, absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource IDs are automatically generated by Android for files inside the resource folder (`/res`) only. Out of that folder, there is no such thing called "resource ID".

Some Android components (such as `View`s) *do have* ID and can be set manually. However, manually-set ID is not listed inside `R.java`, the collection of resource IDs generated by Android.

But in your case, generated images don't have ID, so it's impossible to get something that doesn't exist beforehand.

---

Regarding the library, there is another function to set the image from source without resource ID:

```
public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    this.mMovie = movie;
    requestLayout();
}
```

Now, looking at the [`Movie`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html) class which is included in Android SDK, there are other functions to decode a source: `decodeByteArray()` and `decodeFile()`. `decodeByteArray()` accepts a byte array, and `decodeFile()` accepts a file path, which can be used if you have the full path to the file.

While `Bitmap` can be converted to byte array, I'm not sure whether `Bitmap` supports multiple layers/animation of a GIF image, so I'll avoid the first approach. Instead, you can try this:

```
GifMovieView gifMovieView = ... ; // the reference to the view
String filePath = ... ; // the full file path to the GIF image

Movie myMovie = Movie.decodeFile(pathName);
gifMovieView.setMovie(myMovie);
```

<sub>(The above code is not tested yet)</sub>

Comment: So basically I have gif stored in my sdcard ( which is created by my app ). I want to load that gif to my viewer. For that I am uisng https://github.com/sbakhtiarov/gif-movie-view/blob/master/src/com/basv/gifmoviewview/widget/GifMovieView.java. And in that setMovieResource expecting a int (resId). But I have all other info like bitmap, absolute path.

Comment: @Achayan I have updated the answer. Note that I didn't test the code, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: @Achayan I just realized that there is `setMovie(Movie movie)` inside that file already. My code basically just reimplemented that function, which *might* be useful, but a bit redundant.

Comment: @Achayan Could you please explain why it didn't work? No error/exception?

Comment: No stacktrace. Not sure whats going wrong. I will check it and let you know later