# Get Resource ID from Uri

Tags: android

Do you guys know if it is possible to get the resource id from a Uri?

For example from

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/raw/" + name);
```

get the equivalent of this

```
R.raw.name
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get resource ID from URI or Bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710240/get-resource-id-from-uri-or-bitmap)

Comment: I read that one before I made this and I do not believe it is a duplicate because that the questioner asked to do something that was impossible. Since I know the resID are in the Raw folder already I am pretty certain this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().
         getIdentifier(name, "raw", context.getPackageName()));
```

Also you can use this

```
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {

    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(variableName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

which is faster than `getIdentifier`

Comment: Thank you for taking my question seriously! This is what I was looking for. I will try to make a method that takes your warning into account.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is if it is possible to get a resource id by its name given in coding then - yes.

```
getIdentifier( name , "raw" , packageName );
```

However thread lightly. It is using reflection and thus may easily break if you for example use proguard. You have been warned.